# Erro no procedimento case 3

Tags: c

Estou com problemas no meu case 3 do meu código em C, ele deveria comparar as duas strings com a função strcmp

```
filmeIgual=strcmp(filmePesquisa,v[x].nome);
```

e se o resultado for zero, `if(filmeIgual == 0)`, as strings serão iguais.

Porém meu código quando executado, dá toda hora que o programa parou de funcionar, já testei de várias maneiras.

Segue o código que estou com problema no case 3, o link do código também está no paste bin caso ajude a entender: https://pastebin.com/F9cPyRkK

O Case 3 deve ser uma função que receberá o a palavra (string) que o usuário digitar e ver se ela existe no vetor v[] que está armazenando estes dados na `struct` Filme com a variável que representa-á filmes

SEGUE CODIGO RESOLVIDO, ABRACOS.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define T 51 // Tamanho maximo sera 50 da constante das strings que vou utilizar
#define Tfilmes 2 // Alterar aqui nessa constante caso deseje alterar quantidade de filmes disponivel para cadastro

struct Filme
{
    char nome[T];
    char diretor[T];
    int anoLancamento, quantAtores;
    float nota;
};

void cadastraFilmes(struct Filme v[], int x) //Procedimento 1 cadastra filmes ao vetor
    {
        if(x < Tfilmes) // Controla quantidade maxima de filmes segundo constante Tfilmes
        {
                printf("Digite o nome do filme: ");
                gets(v[x].nome);
                printf("Digite o nome do diretor: ");
                gets(v[x].diretor);
                printf("Digite o ano do lancamento do filme: ");
                scanf("%d%*c",&v[x].anoLancamento);
                while(v[x].anoLancamento < 2010) // Verifica se o ano de lancamento digitado e superior a 2010
                    {
                        printf("\nSo podem ser cadastrados filmes lancados a partir de 2010, tente novamente!\n");
                        printf("\nDigite o ano do lancamento do filme: ");
                        scanf("%d%*c",&v[x].anoLancamento);
                    }
                printf("Digite a quantidade de atores: ");
                scanf("%d%*c",&v[x].quantAtores);
                printf("Digite a nota recebida pela critica: ");
                scanf("%f%*c",&v[x].nota);
                printf("\n");
                printf("\tFilme cadastrado com sucesso!\n\n"); // Confirmacao de cadastro efetuado com sucesso
                system("pause");
        }
        else // Se a quantidade maxima de filmes já estiver sido cadastradaa, avisa o usuario e nao deixa o mesmo cadastrar mais
        {
            printf("\t\nQuantidade maxima de filmes ja cadastrada no vetor!\n\n");
            system("pause");
        }
    }

void diretorAno(struct Filme v[]) // Procedimento 2 pesquisa se a string nomeDiretor digitada e a data de lancamento desejada existem
    {
            char nomeDiretor[T];
            int x,pesquisaAno,nomeDiretorIgual;
            printf("Digite o nome do diretor para pesquisa: ");
            gets(nomeDiretor);
            printf("Digite a data de lancamento desejada: ");
            scanf("%d%*c",&pesquisaAno);
            for(x=0;x<Tfilmes;x++)
            {
                nomeDiretorIgual=strcmp(nomeDiretor,v[x].diretor); // funcao strcmp verifica se duas strings sao iguais
                if(nomeDiretorIgual == 0 && pesquisaAno == v[x].anoLancamento) // se nome diretor e data lancamento forem iguais as digitadas e existirem no vetor, lista na tela
                    {
                        printf("\n=================DIRETOR E DATAS DE LANCAMENTOS ENCONTRADOS===========================\n");
                        printf("\n\tNome do filme: %s", v[x].nome);
                        printf("\n\tNome do diretor: %s", v[x].diretor);
                        printf("\n\tAno de lancamento do filme: %d", v[x].anoLancamento);
                        printf("\n\tQuantidade de atores: %d", v[x].quantAtores);
                        printf("\n\tNota recebida pela critica: %.2f\n", v[x].nota);
                        printf("\n=================DIRETOR E DATAS DE LANCAMENTOS ENCONTRADOS===========================\n\n");
                        system("pause");
                    }
                else // caso nao sejam encontrados e mostrado na tela a negativa
                    {
                        printf("\t\nDiretor e data de lancamento nao encontradas, por favor tente novamente.\n\n");
                        system("pause");
                    }
            }
    }

void nomesFilme(struct Filme v[]) // Procedimento 3 pesquisara se o nome informado de filme existe
    {
            char nome[T];
            int x, filmeIgual;
            char filmePesquisa[Tfilmes];
            printf("Digite o nome do filme para pesquisa: ");
            gets(filmePesquisa);
            for(x=0;x<Tfilmes;x++) // percorre vetor com limite maximo definido pela constante la em cima
            {
                filmeIgual=strcmp(filmePesquisa,v[x].nome); // funcao strcmp compara 2 strings
                if(filmeIgual == 0) // se o da strcmp for zero, significa que sao iguais
                    {
                        printf("\n=================DIRETOR E DATAS DE LANCAMENTOS ENCONTRADOS===========================\n");
                        printf("\n\tNome do filme: %s", v[x].nome);
                        printf("\n\tNome do diretor: %s", v[x].diretor);
                        printf("\n\tAno de lancamento do filme: %d", v[x].anoLancamento);
                        printf("\n\tQuantidade de atores: %d", v[x].quantAtores);
                        printf("\n\tNota recebida pela critica: %.2f\n", v[x].nota);
                        printf("\n=================DIRETOR E DATAS DE LANCAMENTOS ENCONTRADOS===========================\n\n");
                        system("pause");
                    }
                else // se nao for igual, neste caso, ja podemos definir que o filme nao foi encontrado no vetor
                    {
                        printf("\t\nFilme nao encontrado.\n\n");
                        system("pause");
                    }
            }
    }

void mostraFilmes(struct Filme v[]) // Procedimento 4 que vai listar todos os filmes ja cadastrados no vetor
    {
        int x;
        for(x=0;x<Tfilmes;x++)
        {
            printf("\n================================================\n");
            printf("\n\tNome do filme: %s", v[x].nome);
            printf("\n\tNome do diretor: %s", v[x].diretor);
            printf("\n\tAno de lancamento do filme: %d", v[x].anoLancamento);
            printf("\n\tQuantidade de atores: %d", v[x].quantAtores);
            printf("\n\tNota recebida pela critica: %.2f\n", v[x].nota);
            printf("\n================================================\n");
        }
        system("pause");
    }

int menu() // Menu central
    {
        int z;
        printf("\n================================================\n");
        printf("\n\n\t\tMENU:\n");
        printf("\n\tDigite a opcao desejada:\n");
        printf("\n\t(1) Cadastrar Filme \n");
        printf("\n\t(2) Pesquisar por ano e diretor \n");
        printf("\n\t(3) Pesquisar por nome do filme \n");
        printf("\n\t(4) Lista todos os filmes cadastrados \n");
        printf("\n\t(5) Sair\n\n");
        printf("\n================================================\n");
        scanf("%d%*c", &z);
        system("cls");
        return z;
    }

int main()
{
    int x=0;
    int op;
    struct Filme filmes[Tfilmes];
    do
    {
        op=menu();
        switch(op)
        {
            case 1:
                cadastraFilmes(filmes,x);
                x++;
                system("cls");
                break;
            case 2:
                diretorAno(filmes);
                system("cls");
                break;
            case 3:
                nomesFilme(filmes);
                system("cls");
                break;
            case 4:
                mostraFilmes(filmes);
                system("cls");
                break;
            case 5:
                system("pause");
                break;
            default:
                printf("\n\tOpcao invalida, tente novamente.\n");
                break;
        }
    }while(op!=5); // coloquei este while e coloquei tambem um case 5 la no menu, nao precisaria portanto o case 5 SE eu nao quisesse colocar um system pause que com o mesmo fica mais claro que o programa foi finalizado.

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Roda o programa com um debbuger e veja o erro que aparece.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define T 51
#define Tfilmes 2

struct Filme
{
    char nome[T];
    char diretor[T];
    int anoLancamento, quantAtores;
    float nota;
};
void cadastraFilmes(struct Filme v[], int x)
{
    if (x < Tfilmes)
    {
        printf("Digite o nome do filme: ");
        gets(v[x].nome);
        printf("Digite o nome do diretor: ");
        gets(v[x].diretor);
        printf("Digite o ano do lancamento do filme: ");
        scanf("%d%*c", &v[x].anoLancamento);
        while (v[x].anoLancamento < 2010)
        {
            printf("\nSo podem ser cadastrados filmes lancados a partir de 2010, tente novamente!\n");
            printf("\nDigite o ano do lancamento do filme: ");
            scanf("%d%*c", &v[x].anoLancamento);
        }
        printf("Digite a quantidade de atores: ");
        scanf("%d%*c", &v[x].quantAtores);
        printf("Digite a nota recebida pela critica: ");
        scanf("%f%*c", &v[x].nota);
        printf("\n");
        printf("\tFilme cadastrado com sucesso!\n\n");
        system("pause");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\t\nQuantidade maxima de filmes ja cadastrada no vetor!\n\n");
        system("pause");
    }
}

void mostraFilmes(struct Filme v[])
{
    int x;
    for (x = 0; x<Tfilmes; x++)
    {
        printf("\n================================================\n");
        printf("\n\tNome do filme: %s", v[x].nome);
        printf("\n\tNome do diretor: %s", v[x].diretor);
        printf("\n\tAno de lancamento do filme: %d", v[x].anoLancamento);
        printf("\n\tQuantidade de atores: %d", v[x].quantAtores);
        printf("\n\tNota recebida pela critica: %.2f\n", v[x].nota);
        printf("\n================================================\n");
    }


}
void diretorAno(struct Filme v[])
{
    char nomeDiretor[T];
    int x, pesquisaAno, nomeDiretorIgual;
    printf("Digite o nome do diretor para pesquisa: ");
    gets(nomeDiretor);
    printf("Digite a data de lancamento desejada: ");
    scanf("%d%*c", &pesquisaAno);
    for (x = 0; x<Tfilmes; x++)
    {

        nomeDiretorIgual = strcmp(nomeDiretor, v[x].diretor);
        if (nomeDiretorIgual == 0 && pesquisaAno == v[x].anoLancamento)
        {
            printf("\n=================DIRETOR E DATAS DE LANCAMENTOS ENCONTRADOS===========================\n");
            printf("\n\tNome do filme: %s", v[x].nome);
            printf("\n\tNome do diretor: %s", v[x].diretor);
            printf("\n\tAno de lancamento do filme: %d", v[x].anoLancamento);
            printf("\n\tQuantidade de atores: %d", v[x].quantAtores);
            printf("\n\tNota recebida pela critica: %.2f\n", v[x].nota);
            printf("\n=================DIRETOR E DATAS DE LANCAMENTOS ENCONTRADOS===========================\n\n");
            system("pause");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\t\nDiretor e data de lancamento nao encontradas, por favor tente novamente.\n\n");
            system("pause");
        }
    }

}
void nomesFilme(struct Filme v[])
{
    char nome[T];
    int x, filmeIgual;
    char filmePesquisa[Tfilmes];
    printf("Digite o nome do filme para pesquisa: ");
    gets(filmePesquisa);
    for (x = 0; x<Tfilmes; x++)
    {
        filmeIgual = strcmp(filmePesquisa, v[x].nome);
        if (filmeIgual == 0)
        {
            printf("\n=================DIRETOR E DATAS DE LANCAMENTOS ENCONTRADOS===========================\n");
            printf("\n\tNome do filme: %s", v[x].nome);
            printf("\n\tNome do diretor: %s", v[x].diretor);
            printf("\n\tAno de lancamento do filme: %d", v[x].anoLancamento);
            printf("\n\tQuantidade de atores: %d", v[x].quantAtores);
            printf("\n\tNota recebida pela critica: %.2f\n", v[x].nota);
            printf("\n=================DIRETOR E DATAS DE LANCAMENTOS ENCONTRADOS===========================\n\n");
            system("pause");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\t\nFilme nao encontrado.\n\n");
            system("pause");
        }
    }

}
int menu()
{
    int z;
    printf("\n================================================\n");
    printf("\n\n\t\tMENU:\n");
    printf("\n\tDigite a opcao desejada:\n");
    printf("\n\t(1) Cadastrar Filme \n");
    printf("\n\t(2) Pesquisar por ano e diretor \n");
    printf("\n\t(3) Pesquisar por nome do filme \n");
    printf("\n\t(4) Lista todos os filmes cadastrados \n");
    printf("\n\t(5) Sair\n\n");
    printf("\n================================================\n");
    scanf("%d%*c", &z);
    system("cls");
    return z;
}
int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    int op;
    struct Filme filmes[Tfilmes];
    do
    {
        op = menu();
        switch (op)
        {
        case 1:
            cadastraFilmes(filmes, x);
            x++;
            system("cls");
            break;
        case 2:
            diretorAno(filmes);
            system("cls");
            break;

        case 3:
            nomesFilme(filmes);
            system("cls");
            break;
        case 4:
            mostraFilmes(filmes);
            system("cls");
            break;
        case 5:
            system("pause");
            break;
        default:
            printf("\n\tOpcao invalida, tente novamente.\n");
            break;
        }
    } while (op != 5);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Deu certo Claudio, muito grato, estava declarando como int a variavel string, mas agora a case 4 parou de funcionar, nada acontece quando a digito, editei o codigo e comentei todo ele pra ficar mais claro, mas mais uma vez obrigado!

Comment: queres que arranje a case 4 ??

Comment: Na realidade, queria uma ajuda do que esta acontecendo com meu vetor no case 4 pois antes funfava e agora nada fica nao respondendo tambem, ela só mostra o vetor preenchido, agora como arrumei a case 3, nao sei por que parece que nao tem nada armazenmado no vetor, mas esta preenchendo certo a case 1

Comment: ok vou ja ler o codigo

Comment: @Claudio ao invés de escrever em outra resposta, é recomendável que você edite esta.

Comment: Obrigado ainda principiante no site

Comment: Percebi que você é novo e que tem boas intenções no site, mas recomendo que antes de responder algumas perguntas, dê uma olhada em [ask] e [answer].

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define T 51
#define Tfilmes 2

struct Filme
{
    char nome[T];
    char diretor[T];
    int anoLancamento, quantAtores;
    float nota;
};
void cadastraFilmes(struct Filme v[], int x)
{
    if (x < Tfilmes)
    {
        printf("Digite o nome do filme: ");
        gets(v[x].nome);
        printf("Digite o nome do diretor: ");
        gets(v[x].diretor);
        printf("Digite o ano do lancamento do filme: ");
        scanf("%d%*c", &v[x].anoLancamento);
        while (v[x].anoLancamento < 2010)
        {
            printf("\nSo podem ser cadastrados filmes lancados a partir de 2010, tente novamente!\n");
            printf("\nDigite o ano do lancamento do filme: ");
            scanf("%d%*c", &v[x].anoLancamento);
        }
        printf("Digite a quantidade de atores: ");
        scanf("%d%*c", &v[x].quantAtores);
        printf("Digite a nota recebida pela critica: ");
        scanf("%f%*c", &v[x].nota);
        printf("\n");
        printf("\tFilme cadastrado com sucesso!\n\n");
        system("pause");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\t\nQuantidade maxima de filmes ja cadastrada no vetor!\n\n");
        system("pause");
    }
}

void mostraFilmes(struct Filme v[])
{
    int x;

    for (x = 0; x<Tfilmes; x++)
    {
        printf("\n================================================\n");
        printf("\n\tNome do filme: %s", v[x].nome);
        printf("\n\tNome do diretor: %s", v[x].diretor);
        printf("\n\tAno de lancamento do filme: %d", v[x].anoLancamento);
        printf("\n\tQuantidade de atores: %d", v[x].quantAtores);
        printf("\n\tNota recebida pela critica: %.2f\n", v[x].nota);
        printf("\n================================================\n");
        system("pause");
    }


}
void diretorAno(struct Filme v[])
{
    char nomeDiretor[T];
    int x, pesquisaAno, nomeDiretorIgual;
    printf("Digite o nome do diretor para pesquisa: ");
    gets(nomeDiretor);
    printf("Digite a data de lancamento desejada: ");
    scanf("%d%*c", &pesquisaAno);
    for (x = 0; x<Tfilmes; x++)
    {

        nomeDiretorIgual = strcmp(nomeDiretor, v[x].diretor);
        if (nomeDiretorIgual == 0 && pesquisaAno == v[x].anoLancamento)
        {
            printf("\n=================DIRETOR E DATAS DE LANCAMENTOS ENCONTRADOS===========================\n");
            printf("\n\tNome do filme: %s", v[x].nome);
            printf("\n\tNome do diretor: %s", v[x].diretor);
            printf("\n\tAno de lancamento do filme: %d", v[x].anoLancamento);
            printf("\n\tQuantidade de atores: %d", v[x].quantAtores);
            printf("\n\tNota recebida pela critica: %.2f\n", v[x].nota);
            printf("\n=================DIRETOR E DATAS DE LANCAMENTOS ENCONTRADOS===========================\n\n");
            system("pause");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\t\nDiretor e data de lancamento nao encontradas, por favor tente novamente.\n\n");
            system("pause");
        }
    }

}
void nomesFilme(struct Filme v[])
{
    char nome[T];
    int x, filmeIgual;
    char filmePesquisa[Tfilmes];
    printf("Digite o nome do filme para pesquisa: ");
    gets(filmePesquisa);
    for (x = 0; x<Tfilmes; x++)
    {
        filmeIgual = strcmp(filmePesquisa, v[x].nome);
        if (filmeIgual == 0)
        {
            printf("\n=================DIRETOR E DATAS DE LANCAMENTOS ENCONTRADOS===========================\n");
            printf("\n\tNome do filme: %s", v[x].nome);
            printf("\n\tNome do diretor: %s", v[x].diretor);
            printf("\n\tAno de lancamento do filme: %d", v[x].anoLancamento);
            printf("\n\tQuantidade de atores: %d", v[x].quantAtores);
            printf("\n\tNota recebida pela critica: %.2f\n", v[x].nota);
            printf("\n=================DIRETOR E DATAS DE LANCAMENTOS ENCONTRADOS===========================\n\n");
            system("pause");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\t\nFilme nao encontrado.\n\n");
            system("pause");
        }
    }

}
int menu()
{
    int z;
    printf("\n================================================\n");
    printf("\n\n\t\tMENU:\n");
    printf("\n\tDigite a opcao desejada:\n");
    printf("\n\t(1) Cadastrar Filme \n");
    printf("\n\t(2) Pesquisar por ano e diretor \n");
    printf("\n\t(3) Pesquisar por nome do filme \n");
    printf("\n\t(4) Lista todos os filmes cadastrados \n");
    printf("\n\t(5) Sair\n\n");
    printf("\n================================================\n");
    scanf("%d%*c", &z);
    system("cls");
    return z;
}
int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    int op;
    struct Filme filmes[Tfilmes];
    do
    {
        op = menu();
        switch (op)
        {
        case 1:
            cadastraFilmes(filmes, x);
            x++;
            system("cls");
            break;
        case 2:
            diretorAno(filmes);
            system("cls");
            break;

        case 3:
            nomesFilme(filmes);
            system("cls");
            break;
        case 4:
            mostraFilmes(filmes);
            system("cls");
            break;
        case 5:
            system("pause");
            break;
        default:
            printf("\n\tOpcao invalida, tente novamente.\n");
            break;
        }
    } while (op != 5);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: O que este código tem de diferente da outra resposta? Por que não editar a que você já respondeu?

Comment: Nesta Resposta o case 4 mostra todos os dados do vetor que antes nao dava.

Comment: Não vejo a necessidade de uma nova resposta pra uma alteração tão pequena. Seria melhor editar o código da outra.

Comment: Entendi o system pause Claudio, porém ela tem que quando ser utilizado o case 4, mostrar TODOS os filmes de uma vez só, e o system pause vai fazer com que eu tenha que ficar apertando alguma tecla para que mostre o proximo filme cadastrado entende